# Method in R to find difference between rows with varying row spacing

Tags: r, dataframe, row, difference

I want to add an extra column in a dataframe which displays the difference between certain rows, where the distance between the rows also depends on values in the table.

I found out that:

```
mutate(Col_new = Col_1 - lead(Col_1, n = x))
```

can find the difference for a fixed n, but only a integer can be used as input. How would you find the difference between rows for a varying distance between the rows?

I am trying to get the output in `Col_new`, which is the difference between the i and i+n row where n should take the value in column `Count`. (The data is rounded so there might be 0.01 discrepancies in `Col_new`).

```
col_1 count Col_new
1   0.90     1   -0.68
2   1.58     1   -0.31
3   1.89     1    0.05
4   1.84     1    0.27
5   1.57     1    0.27
6   1.30     2   -0.26
7   1.25     2   -0.99
8   1.56     2   -1.58
9   2.24     2   -1.80
10  3.14     2   -1.58
11  4.04     3   -0.95
12  4.72     3    0.01
13  5.04     3    0.60
14  4.99     3    0.60
15  4.71     3    0.01
16  4.44     4   -1.84
17  4.39     4      NA
18  4.70     4      NA
19  5.38     4      NA
20  6.28     4      NA
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to provide your data and a reproducible example? Screenshots are not ideal

Answer (score 1):

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(Col_1 = c(0.90, 1.58, 1.89, 1.84, 1.57, 1.30, 1.35, 
                 1.56, 2.24, 3.14, 4.04, 4.72, 5.04, 4.99, 
                 4.71, 4.44, 4.39, 4.70, 5.38, 6.28),
       Count = sort(rep(1:4, 5)))
```

Some code that generates the intended output, but can undoubtably be made more efficient.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(col_2 = sapply(1:4, function(s){lead(Col_1, n = s)})) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Col_new = Col_1 - col_2[Count]) %>%
  select(-col_2)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 20 × 3
# Rowwise: 
   Col_1 Count Col_new
   <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
 1  0.9      1 -0.68  
 2  1.58     1 -0.310 
 3  1.89     1  0.0500
 4  1.84     1  0.27  
 5  1.57     1  0.27  
 6  1.3      2 -0.26  
 7  1.35     2 -0.89  
 8  1.56     2 -1.58  
 9  2.24     2 -1.8   
10  3.14     2 -1.58  
11  4.04     3 -0.95  
12  4.72     3  0.0100
13  5.04     3  0.600 
14  4.99     3  0.600 
15  4.71     3  0.0100
16  4.44     4 -1.84  
17  4.39     4 NA     
18  4.7      4 NA     
19  5.38     4 NA     
20  6.28     4 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% mutate(Col_new = case_when(
df$count == 1 ~ df$col_1 - lead(df$col_1 , n = 1),
df$count == 2 ~ df$col_1  - lead(df$col_1 , n = 2),
df$count == 3 ~ df$col_1  - lead(df$col_1 , n = 3),
df$count == 4 ~ df$col_1  - lead(df$col_1 , n = 4),
df$count == 5 ~ df$col_1  - lead(df$col_1 , n = 5)
))

   col_1 count Col_new
1   0.90     1   -0.68
2   1.58     1   -0.31
3   1.89     1    0.05
4   1.84     1    0.27
5   1.57     1    0.27
6   1.30     2   -0.26
7   1.25     2   -0.99
8   1.56     2   -1.58
9   2.24     2   -1.80
10  3.14     2   -1.58
11  4.04     3   -0.95
12  4.72     3    0.01
13  5.04     3    0.60
14  4.99     3    0.60
15  4.71     3    0.01
16  4.44     4   -1.84
17  4.39     4      NA
18  4.70     4      NA
19  5.38     4      NA
20  6.28     4      NA
```

This would give you your desired results but is not a very good solution for more cases. Imagine your task with 10 or more different counts another solution is required.